# Is there a way in ida pro to see the address where I have explicitly marked them as code or data, etc?

Tags: ida, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I'm analyzing an obfuscated binary.  IDA did a pretty good job of doing the initial auto-analysis.  Later, I went through and marked some sections as undefined, or code, etc.  Now IDA can't re-create a section as a function. It complains about

```
The function has undefined instruction/data at the specified address.
```

I think this is because it has remembered where I've marked thing as undefined or data or code.  And those marks are confusing the auto analyzer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, IDA does not keep a separate list of addresses handled by the user.

Normally the message you quote should mention the address of the problem so you can double-click it to jump there and fix the issue (e.g. convert data to code). If there are many such places, you can also try a mass selection and [force everything in a range to code](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/igor-tip-of-the-week-04-more-selection/) (though this may backfire if code is obfuscated).